# Access class template arguments in member function

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

I'd like to have a HandlerGroup that can wrap a bunch of handlers to be used later. Here's my designed API:

```
void handler1(Data* d) {}
void handler2(Data* d) {}
void handler3(Data* d) {}

using Handler = std::function<void(Data*)>;

template <typename... Handlers>
struct HandlerGroup {
    void run(Data* data) {
    // ??? how to access variadic handlers defined in template arguments
    // for (handler : Handlers...) handler(data);
    }
}

void driver(Data* data) {
    HandlerGroup<handler1, handler2, handler3>::run(data);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since C++17 you should use `auto...` as template parameters,by this you can instatiate your template with passed pointers to function.

Then you can create in based-range for loop initializer list with unpacked `Handler(functionPointer)`, and just call `function` wrapper:

```
using Handler = std::function<void(Data*)>;

template <auto... Handlers>
struct HandlerGroup {
    static void run(Data* data) {
        for (const auto& handler :  {Handler(Handlers)...})
            handler(data);
    }
};

void driver(Data* data) 
{
    HandlerGroup<handler1, handler2, handler3>::run(data);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/nEvsTPsf7)

Comment: great answer! but how can I achieve this with c++11/14?

Comment: @pedim C++14 [live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/a5eY7oo4Y), or [another version](https://godbolt.org/z/bh6j9q9qc) without `function`, you can just unpack pointers to function into initializer list and call them.

Comment: Much appreciated!

Comment: Folding expression `(Handlers(data), ...);` instead of for-range, as we are in C++17.